# Sylvester's law of inertia for generic matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

By [Sylvester's law of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia), the positive and negative indices of a symmetric matrix $A$ are also the number of positive and negative eigenvalues of $A$. I was wondering if a similar result is known for a generic matrix $A$.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first requirement if such a generalization is to be acquired is to have an analogous notion of indices. However, for matrix with real entries, $A$ is symmetric if and only if $A$ is congruent to a diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are $0$, $1$, and $-1$. If $A$ is not symmetric, we cannot conjugate it to get the indices. Another stumbling block of course is that not all matrices with real entries have real eigenvalues. The matrix $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}$ has eigenvalues $\pm i$. So we cannot talk much about ''positive/negative/zero'' eigenvalues that correspond to ''positive/negative/zero'' indices.